# Multiclass Classification for ANN

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network

I am using ANN for Multiclass Classification(12 classes) in Python. However i am getting errors. Here is the code snippet:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the ANN
# Initialising the ANN
classifier = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 4))

# Adding the second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the output layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 13, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'softmax'))

# Compiling the ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size =200 , epochs = 100)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

   # Making the Confusion Matrix
   from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
   cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

The program runs all the way until running the neural code and also finds the y_pred. After that i get this error i.e the confusion matrix is not formed.

The error:

`ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput targets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

predictions = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1) 

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

I hope it will resolve your problem

Answer (score -2):

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test) 
predictions = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1) 

label_encoder = LabelEncoder().fit(y_test)
label_y = label_encoder.transform(y_test)

cm = confusion_matrix(label_y, predictions)
```